# Material Angular scrolls to top on opening of mat-select and hides

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my application I'm using material select component.

Expected behavior I want to achieve is: when i open selector field that is bounded to selector should scroll to top of viewport and options should appear underneath.

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6s73z

I found an issue that when the selector is close to the bottom of viewport options will end up out of screen.

**Issue**: https://streamable.com/r3ekd

I cannot find a way to fix it. I tried implementing my custom scroll strategy where I was using `scrollIntoView` and then manually repositioned a select panel when it overflow a content. It was buggy on android and iOS so i abandoned this idea.

Did anyone had similar problem? How to fix that issue? Maybe there's something I missed?

**Custom scroll strategy**

```
enable() {
  setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#field').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(() => {
    this.overlayRef.updatePosition();
  });

  this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().pipe(debounceTime(50), take(1)).subscribe(() => {
    if (parseFloat(this.overlayRef.hostElement.style.top) <= 0) {
      this.overlayRef.overlayElement.style.top = coerceCssPixelValue(12);
    }
  });
  this.overlayRef.updatePosition();

  disablePageScroll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice observation.

Upon investigation it became clear that

- `mat-select` was taken to the top of the view... and placement of the `mat-select` was correct in all cases (when `mat-select` was in the middle of the view and when `mat-select` was at the very bottom of the view)
- the issue was with the div which opens up when we click on `mat-select` it has the `cdk-overlay-10` class on it; On this div, There is a css `bottom` value assigned to it inline [this is where the issue is and it is this `bottom` value that pushes the div off-screen]
- **solution** is: set a `top:0` on this div and our problem will be resolved... only one caveat that when we click on `mat-select` 2 things happen: (1) page scrolls (2) options div becomes visible... so an **improved solution** would be to have a custom animation that displays the div slowly so that the scrolling is finished before the div becomes visible.

relevant **CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane{top:0 !important; 
opacity: 1; animation:slowReveal 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes slowReveal{
  from{opacity:0.5;}
  to{opacity:1;}
}
```

complete [forked working stackblitz is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6s73z-ezngqc?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.css)